# What will happen to SQL Service Account when SQL Server is uninstalled?

Tags: sql-server

We are planning to downgrade from Enterprise/Standard version of SQL Server to Developer Edition. We will move the existing system and user database to the Dev Edition.

Are we going to need to request for a new Service Account to be created for the SQL Services of the Developer Edition? The existing account was created by the previous DBA. The account details were not shared with us.

We are looking into two options that reuse the old account, but we will ask the security team to reset the password, or if it will be deleted when we downgrade we will request new accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are we going to need to request for a new Service Account to be created for the SQL Services of the Developer Edition?

You can re-use the service account, assuming you know the information or can reset the information (password, for example) if it's not known. Managed Service Accounts (MSA's) can be re-used on the same server, but if moving between servers or renaming servers would need to have their metadata changed in active directory and uninstalled from the previous server, first.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. Big help guys.